# AJAX a PHP as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Try this bit of code someplace:

```
$("html").load("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GoOvplDFuqx--ul60ATB1HfDz0o793g6ICD0VJnEHfc/export?format=txt",'',function(resp,x,y){document.write(resp);})
```

It's essentially a mirror of today's Wikipedia on my Google pseudo-CDN. However, I also tried this:

```
$("html").load("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page",'',function(resp,x,y){document.write(resp);})
```

and it doesn't work.

Reference screenshots:

[image: works]

[image: doesn't work]

**How can I fetch a dynamic site as HTML for printing?**

Comment: @Ankit But my first example loaded from Google. My base site was StackOverflow.

Comment: Is it a chrome extension?

Comment: @Ankit No. I'm just having fun from the console.

Comment: It seems that the loaded resource must specify `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the header to allow being loaded from another domain. More about this topic here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

It is like you have a crossdomain problem because there is no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response. If this is not the case a browser usually does not allow to request a service located on another domain than the javascript that is triggering the request.

Use some server script to get the content from the particular url or use mod_proxy on the server config